# How to find whether data is in English language or in Chinese language

Tags: java, cjk

I am reading an Excel sheet where i am having English and Chinese language Description. I want to Distinguish these data.

How to do this in Java.

what is the ASCII range value for the Chinese character.

Comment: ASCII and Chinese it's just impossible, you should have/use an UTF charset.

Comment: Interesting Java applet to detect what kind of chinese character set used...http://www.mandarintools.com/sinodetect.html Maybe you can check this website for a guidance http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html or http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether you have all English (ASCII) character in your string, you can check for ASCII range like this:

```
// assuming str is your text with some bunch of characters
// returns true if contains all ASCII characters
boolean b = str.matches("^[\u0000-\u0080]+$");
```

To check CJK strokes, Unicode range is

```
[\u31C0-\u31EF]
```

[Visit this page](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) for various Unicode block ranges.

Comment: But what if he has a non-ASCII non-Chinese character?

Comment: If he has non-ASCII characters in the string above matches method will just return false.

Comment: @anubhava: What will be the result if String contains both English and Chinese character.

Comment: It will return false if **even 1 non-ASCII character is present** in the string.

Comment: ASCII range stops at 0x7F / \u007F. And Chinese strokes are of very little use... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166130/what-is-the-upper-and-lower-bound-for-chinese-char-in-utf-8