# How to find out Chinese or Japanese Character in a String in Python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Such as:

```
str = 'sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf'
```

Add `()` to Chinese and Japanese Characters:

```
strAfterConvert = 'sdfasfasf(天地方益)3(権)sdfsdf'
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The version of python is Python2

Comment: Since this is rather broad and I don't want to look up the ranges: you'd decode from UTF-8 to get `unicode` objects, then use a regex to detect specific *ranges* of Unicode codepoints. What those ranges are for Chinese and Japanese is an exercise in research into the Unicode standard.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: From the link I posted above you could iterate over the characters and test the value of `ord` against the various CJK ranges for Chinese chracters

Comment: @EdChum Sorry, this is wildly off-topic - but you should change your profile text (I checked your prof for the lulz) from " peoples' " to " people's ". Otherwise, you're saying that hell is the code of other ethnic groups/nations (a people).

Comment: @EvenLisle Hmm, maybe I really do think that also though....

Comment: Hah, yeah I suppose :-P

Comment: Avoid using reserved words as variable names. e.g. str

Answer (score 30):

As a start, you can check if the character is in one of the following unicode blocks:

- [Unicode Block 'CJK Unified Ideographs'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs/index.htm) - U+4E00 to U+9FFF
- [Unicode Block 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs_extension_a/index.htm)  - U+3400 to U+4DBF
- [Unicode Block 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs_extension_b/index.htm) - U+20000 to U+2A6DF
- [Unicode Block 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs_extension_c/index.htm) - U+2A700 to U+2B73F
- [Unicode Block 'CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs_extension_d/index.htm) - U+2B740 to U+2B81F

---

After that, all you need to do is iterate through the string, checking if the char is Chinese, Japanese or Korean (CJK) and append accordingly:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
ranges = [
  {"from": ord(u"\u3300"), "to": ord(u"\u33ff")},         # compatibility ideographs
  {"from": ord(u"\ufe30"), "to": ord(u"\ufe4f")},         # compatibility ideographs
  {"from": ord(u"\uf900"), "to": ord(u"\ufaff")},         # compatibility ideographs
  {"from": ord(u"\U0002F800"), "to": ord(u"\U0002fa1f")}, # compatibility ideographs
  {'from': ord(u'\u3040'), 'to': ord(u'\u309f')},         # Japanese Hiragana
  {"from": ord(u"\u30a0"), "to": ord(u"\u30ff")},         # Japanese Katakana
  {"from": ord(u"\u2e80"), "to": ord(u"\u2eff")},         # cjk radicals supplement
  {"from": ord(u"\u4e00"), "to": ord(u"\u9fff")},
  {"from": ord(u"\u3400"), "to": ord(u"\u4dbf")},
  {"from": ord(u"\U00020000"), "to": ord(u"\U0002a6df")},
  {"from": ord(u"\U0002a700"), "to": ord(u"\U0002b73f")},
  {"from": ord(u"\U0002b740"), "to": ord(u"\U0002b81f")},
  {"from": ord(u"\U0002b820"), "to": ord(u"\U0002ceaf")}  # included as of Unicode 8.0
]

def is_cjk(char):
  return any([range["from"] <= ord(char) <= range["to"] for range in ranges])

def cjk_substrings(string):
  i = 0
  while i<len(string):
    if is_cjk(string[i]):
      start = i
      while is_cjk(string[i]): i += 1
      yield string[start:i]
    i += 1

string = "sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf".decode("utf-8")
for sub in cjk_substrings(string):
  string = string.replace(sub, "(" + sub + ")")
print string
```

The above prints

```
sdf344asfasf(天地方益)3(権)sdfsdf
```

To be future-proof, you might want to keep a lookout for CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E. It will [ship with Unicode 8.0](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/), which is [scheduled for release in June 2015](http://blog.unicode.org/2015/03/unicode-80-beta-review.html). I've added it to the ranges, but you shouldn't include it until Unicode 8.0 is released.

**[EDIT]**

Added [CJK compatibility ideographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs#CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs), [Japanese Kana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana) and [CJK radicals](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2E80.pdf).

Comment: That doesn't cover all the various ranges: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode

Comment: @EdChum I've updated my answer to include the available unicode ranges.

Comment: Those ranges will miss Japanese Kana characters and a bunch of CJK symbols, strokes, radicals, compatibility characters, and phonetic extensions. It would be easier, and more reliable, to check the Unicode "Script" property.

Comment: @一二三 Updated answer to include CJK compatibility ideographs and Japanese Kana.

Comment: @一二三 Thanks for your suggestions, added CJK radicals supplement. Anything still missing?

Comment: I think this is a fairly complete list: http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Script=Han:][:Script=Bopo:][:Script=Hira:][:Script=Katakana:]

Comment: I can't see anything there that's not in my answer (although I haven't combed through it thoroughly). I haven't been able to find a solid ready-to-use library for this, so if you've got some specific unicode subset in mind, I'd appreciate if you mentioned it.

Comment: You're missing the very first character in there. As I mentioned in my first comment, you should be checking the "Script" property of each character—not checking blocks. The list I posted shows the script subset I think would be appropriate.

Comment: I got a 'TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found' for {"from": ord(u"\U0002a700"), "to": ord(u"\U0002b73f")} and all the other rows containing "\U". Can you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @JFreebird I got this too. Different compilations of python have different character ranges. Instead of using `ord` to build the ranges, use hex strings like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9169489/306503

Comment: The range for hiragana is missing. Please add {'from': ord(u'\u3040'), 'to': ord(u'\u309f')}.

Comment: nice work, but using builtin names like `range` for local variables is a bad practice

Comment: also you don't need to build a list for evaluation by `any()` (generator expression will suffice)

Answer (score 22):

You can do the edit using the [`regex` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which supports checking the Unicode "[Script](http://unicode.org/reports/tr24/)" property of each character and is a drop-in replacement for the `re` package:

```
import regex as re

pattern = re.compile(r'([\p{IsHan}\p{IsBopo}\p{IsHira}\p{IsKatakana}]+)', re.UNICODE)

input = u'sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf'
output = pattern.sub(r'(\1)', input)
print output  # Prints: sdf344asfasf(天地方益)3(権)sdfsdf
```

You should adjust the `\p{Is...}` sequences with the character scripts/blocks that you consider to be "Chinese or Japanese".

Comment: Can `regex` tell which type it belongs to?

Answer (score 9):

From [one of the bleeding edge branch of `NLTK`](https://github.com/alvations/nltk/blob/79eed6ddea0d0a2c212c1060b477fc268fec4d4b/nltk/tokenize/util.py) inspired by the [Moses Machine Translation Toolkit](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder):

```
def is_cjk(character):
    """"
    Checks whether character is CJK.

        >>> is_cjk(u'\u33fe')
        True
        >>> is_cjk(u'\uFE5F')
        False

    :param character: The character that needs to be checked.
    :type character: char
    :return: bool
    """
    return any([start <= ord(character) <= end for start, end in 
                [(4352, 4607), (11904, 42191), (43072, 43135), (44032, 55215), 
                 (63744, 64255), (65072, 65103), (65381, 65500), 
                 (131072, 196607)]
                ])
```

For the specifics of the `ord()` numbers:

```
class CJKChars(object):
    """
    An object that enumerates the code points of the CJK characters as listed on
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane

    This is a Python port of the CJK code point enumerations of Moses tokenizer:
    https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/detokenizer.perl#L309
    """
    # Hangul Jamo (1100–11FF)
    Hangul_Jamo = (4352, 4607) # (ord(u"\u1100"), ord(u"\u11ff"))

    # CJK Radicals Supplement (2E80–2EFF)
    # Kangxi Radicals (2F00–2FDF)
    # Ideographic Description Characters (2FF0–2FFF)
    # CJK Symbols and Punctuation (3000–303F)
    # Hiragana (3040–309F)
    # Katakana (30A0–30FF)
    # Bopomofo (3100–312F)
    # Hangul Compatibility Jamo (3130–318F)
    # Kanbun (3190–319F)
    # Bopomofo Extended (31A0–31BF)
    # CJK Strokes (31C0–31EF)
    # Katakana Phonetic Extensions (31F0–31FF)
    # Enclosed CJK Letters and Months (3200–32FF)
    # CJK Compatibility (3300–33FF)
    # CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A (3400–4DBF)
    # Yijing Hexagram Symbols (4DC0–4DFF)
    # CJK Unified Ideographs (4E00–9FFF)
    # Yi Syllables (A000–A48F)
    # Yi Radicals (A490–A4CF)
    CJK_Radicals = (11904, 42191) # (ord(u"\u2e80"), ord(u"\ua4cf"))

    # Phags-pa (A840–A87F)
    Phags_Pa = (43072, 43135) # (ord(u"\ua840"), ord(u"\ua87f"))

    # Hangul Syllables (AC00–D7AF)
    Hangul_Syllables = (44032, 55215) # (ord(u"\uAC00"), ord(u"\uD7AF"))

    # CJK Compatibility Ideographs (F900–FAFF)
    CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs = (63744, 64255) # (ord(u"\uF900"), ord(u"\uFAFF"))

    # CJK Compatibility Forms (FE30–FE4F)
    CJK_Compatibility_Forms = (65072, 65103) # (ord(u"\uFE30"), ord(u"\uFE4F"))

    # Range U+FF65–FFDC encodes halfwidth forms, of Katakana and Hangul characters
    Katakana_Hangul_Halfwidth = (65381, 65500) # (ord(u"\uFF65"), ord(u"\uFFDC"))

    # Supplementary Ideographic Plane 20000–2FFFF
    Supplementary_Ideographic_Plane = (131072, 196607) # (ord(u"\U00020000"), ord(u"\U0002FFFF"))

    ranges = [Hangul_Jamo, CJK_Radicals, Phags_Pa, Hangul_Syllables, 
              CJK_Compatibility_Ideographs, CJK_Compatibility_Forms, 
              Katakana_Hangul_Halfwidth, Supplementary_Ideographic_Plane]
```

Combining the `is_cjk()` in this answer and @EvenLisle substring answer

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize.util import is_cjk
>>> text = u'sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf'
>>> [1 if is_cjk(ch) else 0 for ch in text]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> def cjk_substrings(string):
...     i = 0
...     while i<len(string):
...         if is_cjk(string[i]):
...             start = i
...             while is_cjk(string[i]): i += 1
...             yield string[start:i]
...         i += 1
... 
>>> string = "sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf".decode("utf-8")
>>> for sub in cjk_substrings(string):
...     string = string.replace(sub, "(" + sub + ")")
... 
>>> string
u'sdf344asfasf(\u5929\u5730\u65b9\u76ca)3(\u6a29)sdfsdf'
>>> print string
sdf344asfasf(天地方益)3(権)sdfsdf
```

Comment: Thx! It works, where @EvenLisle's answer failed: `ﾃﾝﾎﾟﾗﾘ`. Minor quibble: `type character: char` in the docstring - it's `str` actually (there's no `char` type in Python)

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use `regex` module that provides access to `IsKatakana`, `IsHan` properties as shown in [@一二三's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100900/4279); you could use character ranges from [@EvenLisle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070664/4279) with stdlib's `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.sub(u"([\u3300-\u33ff\ufe30-\ufe4f\uf900-\ufaff\U0002f800-\U0002fa1f\u30a0-\u30ff\u2e80-\u2eff\u4e00-\u9fff\u3400-\u4dbf\U00020000-\U0002a6df\U0002a700-\U0002b73f\U0002b740-\U0002b81f\U0002b820-\U0002ceaf]+)", r"(\1)", u'sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf'))
sdf344asfasf(天地方益)3(権)sdfsdf
```

Beware of [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11415841/4279).

You could also check Unicode category:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category(u'天')
'Lo'
>>> unicodedata.category(u's')
'Ll'
```

Answer (score 0):

This basic approach worked for me in Python 3, just to find CJK or other characters:

```py
import unicodedata

def has_unicode_group(text):
    for char in text:
        for name in ('CJK','CHINESE','KATAKANA','HANGUL',):
            if name in unicodedata.name(char):
                return True
    return False
```

Names can be found here: https://www.unicode.org/Public/15.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt