# How to check if text is Japanese Hiragana in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm making a web crawler using python scrapy to collect text from websites.

I only want to collect Japanese Hiragana text. Is there a solution to detect Japanese Hiragana text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only need Hiragana, and you can convert your text to unicode / utf8:

Hiragana is [Unicode code block U+3040 - U+309F](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3040.pdf), so you could test it with:

```py
def char_is_hiragana(c) -> bool:
    return u'\u3040' <= c <= u'\u309F'
def string_is_hiragana(s: str) -> bool:
    return all(char_is_hiragana(c) for c in s)

print('ぁ', string_is_hiragana('ぁ'))
print('ひらがな', string_is_hiragana('ひらがな'))
print('a', string_is_hiragana('a'))
print('english', string_is_hiragana('english'))
```

```
ぁ True
ひらがな True
a False
english False
```

But note that this excludes **historic and non-standard hiragana (hentaigana)**, whitespace, punctuation, Katakana and Kanji:

```py
# hiragana
print('ひらがな', string_is_hiragana('ひらがな'))
# katakana
print('カタカナ', string_is_hiragana('カタカナ'))
# kanji
print('漢字', string_is_hiragana('漢字'))
# punctuation
print('ひらがなもじ「ゆ」', string_is_hiragana('ひらがな「ゆ」'))
print('いいひと。', string_is_hiragana('いいひと。'))
```

```
ひらがな True
カタカナ False
漢字 False
ひらがなもじ「ゆ」 False
いいひと。 False
```

---

You could allow Whitespace:

```py
import string
def string_is_hiragana_or_whitespace(s: str) -> bool:
    return all(c in string.whitespace or char_is_hiragana(c) for c in s)

print('ひらがな  ひらがな', string_is_hiragana_or_whitespace('ひらがな  ひらがな'))
```

```
ひらがな  ひらがな True
```

But I would avoid going down this path of being too specific, there are a lot of difficult problems, like encoding, half-width characters, emoji, CJK code blocks, loan words, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One option is the [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/) library.

```
pip install langdetect
```

Then in your code:

```
from langdetect import detect
detect("ハローワールド")
```

Will return the language code of the text i.e. `ja`

Japanese text tends to be a mix of hiragana, katakana and kanji though. Does it need to specifically identify hiragana?

Comment: yes. actually, it needs to specifically identify hiragana.

Answer (score 0):

See also handy Regex \p that is albe to detect the various alphabets:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100900/3944480

```
import regex as re

pattern = re.compile(r'([\p{IsHan}\p{IsBopo}\p{IsHira}\p{IsKatakana}]+)', re.UNICODE)

input = u'sdf344asfasf天地方益3権sdfsdf'
output = pattern.sub(r'(\1)', input)
print output  # Prints: sdf344asfasf(天地方益)3(権)sdfsdf
```