# c++ check utf8 string contain specified characters

Tags: c++, utf-8

Given an utf8 string, how to know it contain specified characters which don't allowed?

The demand is the utf8 string only can contain English characters and Chinese characters. Any other characters like symbols, numbers, white space, '\n' ... are disallowed.

Dose std::regex can do this job?

```
bool legal(const std::string& s) { // s is utf8 string
   //??
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of a Chinese character that *can* be included in a string with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Any Chinese character, any English character are allowed

Comment: You might find it a challenge fitting all Chinese characters into a UTF-8 encoded string.

Comment: some other language can do this like python. But I don't know std::regex can do this or not. If it can't, seems the only way is check the encoding range of chinese characters

Comment: You should walk the string, decoding UTF-8 sequences to Unicode codepoint numbers on the fly; then compare them against your allowed ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the `std::string` to a vector of utf32 code points (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711618/how-to-get-the-unicode-code-from-each-character-of-a-utf-8-string)) and then iterate them and check the ranges (however I cannot provide the utf32 value ranges for Chinese letters and judging from the comments on your question that could actually be an issue).

**EDIT**

As stated in the comment below, if you know that the characters that you need to validate fall in the 2 byte range you could stick with utf16.

Comment: I *thought* you'd tend to use UTF-16 and `std::wstring`.

Comment: @Bathsheba as I stated in my response I am not very familiar with the actual code ranges, but a quick look a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166130/what-are-the-upper-and-lower-bound-for-chinese-char-in-utf-8 shows that the Chinese characters actually go out of the 2byte range, thus, purely from the point of ease, itearating utf32 code points would be more generic.

Comment: It isn't even necessary to actually convert the whole string, iterating over code points in an UTF-8 string is quite easy (actually, it's trivial using a library such as UTF-8 cpp).